# <bgsound> is not working on IE11 on Windows 10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, audio, web, windows-10

I have a bgsound tag in my application and it works fine on IE on Windows 8.1 and Windows 8 and Windows 7 but it is not working on windows 10.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<bgsound src="wishin.wav">
</body>
```

Comment: See mozilla for information about bgsound compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/bgsound

Comment: It only works on IE. I know that.. the problem is that it is not working on IE on Windows 10

Comment: Does this site work? http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/sounds/bgsoundtest.html

Comment: @libertyernie no it is not working on IE on Windows 10

Comment: @Ala That's odd. It works on IE/Windows 10 for me.

Answer (score 1):

This element is obsolete and should no longer be used. Use [audio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772923.aspx?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP5000527) element instead.

Comment: It is working on Windows 7. Is it obsolete on Windows 10?

Comment: It is obsolete in HTML5.